# TikZ: Why would a decoration cause a dimension too big?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);

  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (4, 0, 0) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(x\)};
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 4, 0) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(y\)};
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 0, 4) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(z\)};

  \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
      mark = at position 0.15 with {\node[font = \scriptsize, above] {C};}
    }]
    \draw[blue, name path = sc] plot[smooth] coordinates
    {(-3, -3, 1) (-1, 1, 2.5) (2, 5, 1.5) (3, 5, 0)};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I add `postaction = decorate` to my blue path, I get a dimension too large
error.  Since the `pos =` option doesn't work with plot, what can I do correct this issue here?

[image]

Comment: It seems only to affect the first part of the path and then only certain values. `pos=.10` works while `.11`, `.12`, …, `.21` don’t (with a variable number of error messages). Decorations and (especially `smooth`) plots both use very tricky things (dividing the path up in very short parts, measuring the path length). Does it need to be `.15`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel no but shouldn't this be fixed?

Comment: `pos=...` syntax is fixed in the CVS version. This error almost always comes from divide by zero (or a very small number) operations either during tangent computations or very small distances. It's more probable that 3D coord system is the culprit here.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a node instead?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);

  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (4, 0, 0) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(x\)};
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 4, 0) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(y\)};
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 0, 4) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(z\)};

  \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
      mark = at position 0.15 with {\node[font = \scriptsize, above] {C};}
    }]
    \draw[blue, name path = sc] plot[smooth] coordinates
    {(-3, -3, 1) (-1, 1, 2.5) (2, 5, 1.5) (3, 5, 0)};
\draw (-3, -3, 1) node[above=-1.5bp]{$c$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because I don't want to play the guessing game on where to put the node.

Comment: You could replace the node code by `\node at (-3, -3, 1 ) [above=-1.5bp] {$c$};` (This won’t help @dustin, anyway …)